# File.ReadAllBytes throwing UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to the path is denied' UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm creating a UWP app, and i'm trying to read an image from a file to a Byte[]. I don't know why but i'm always getting the exception from whatever file path... I tried running that same method File.ReadAllBytes from a different project and it didn't throw the exception. Is it a problem of permissions in my project?

```cs
Foto = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\users\migue\Desktop\aladin.jpg");
```

```xml
<Package
  ...
  xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
  IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp uap5 rescap">
...
<Capabilities>
    <rescap:Capability Name="broadFileSystemAccess" />
</Capabilities>
```

I tried using this example code in my appmanifest, but it doesn't work. The code is in microsoft docs page.

Comment: I guess, that you need to enable the appropriate app capability for that, look for details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions)

Comment: Yes, the UWP sandbox restricts access to the user's files.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than accessing files directly by path, it is recommended to use `FileOpenPicker` to open the file in UWP.

You can use this code:

```cs
public async static Task<StorageFile> OpenLocalFile(params string[] types)
{
    var picker = new FileOpenPicker();
    picker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary;
    Regex typeReg = new Regex(@"^\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
    foreach (var type in types)
    {
        if (type == "*" || typeReg.IsMatch(type))
            picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(type);
        else
            throw new InvalidCastException("File extension is incorrect");
    }
    var file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
    if (file != null)
        return file;
    else
        return null;
}
```

**Usage**

```cs
var file = await OpenLocalFile(".jpg");
var bytes = (await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(file)).ToArray();
```

Best regards.

Comment: Can you explain better how that code works? im a begginer in uwp, thanks in advance

Comment: In the `OpenLocalFile` method, `params string[]`means that you can pass multiple string parameters or an array of strings, which is useful for applications that need to open multiple formats. After passing in the parameters, we need to verify whether the parameters conform to the file extension format (such as `.jpg`, `.png`). After that, we use `FileOpenPicker` for file selection. If you want to learn more, please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.pickers.fileopenpicker)